# Computer damaging multiple USB disk devices?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, usb-flash-drive

We had a customer machine that purportedly ate three different USB disk devices - two flash, and one Western Digital Passport (enclosed spinning disk). One device would actually be recognized afterward, but could not be formatted, re-initialized, scanned, repaired, etc. by any OS. The passport and the other flash disk were not even recognized. The passport was powered, but the flash drive would not even light up. Anyone heard of this before? Windows 7 machine, older, full of dust, USB 3.0 front and rear.

Comment: it's certainly possible.. sounds like a bad power supply unit.. the other thing that perhaps it might possibly be is bad power in the building but i'm not sure about that one.. Certainly chief (And arguably only) suspect, is bad power supply.  I haven't had it happen to me and I don't think i've heard of it put that explicitly, but i've often heard of a bad power supply damaging components, including damaging  a motherboard. And of course it supples power to the USB provided by the motherboard. So it's totally plausible for a bad power supply to do that, and you have ample evidence.

Comment: one further test you could do is change the power supply, see if it kills a cheap usb.. then change the power supply back to the bad one and see if it kills the usb. Another test you could do is backprobing it with a multimeter (though since such a test is very uncomprehensive, it won't prove if a psu is good, but it's the case that if it shows a psu as bad then you'd know it's bad.. If it doesn't show a psu is bad then it might still be bad). I've often shown - proven - a PSU to be bad with that multimeter test.

Comment: Thanks for the validation @barlop - I doubt I'll get to test the theory, I just wondered if anyone else had run into this before. I did unplug the headers to the front usb, though - just in case the PC was turned back on after retirement for some reason. Probably a post-it would have been more ideal.

Comment: Personally i'd remove the power supply and stick a postit on it saying "probably bad", or throw the power supply out..  There are various so-called "rails" that a power supply has and each has various wires associated with it.. So I think there's a 5VSB (so-called 5V stand by) rail.. Some motherboards have a jumper to switch whether USB uses 5VSB or the regular 5V. so it's possible that if the regular 5V is ok or better than the 5VSB, you'd be better off setting it on that.   But really if a power supply has even one bad rail it probably has more and it's too dodgy and better not used at all.

Comment: I guess a postit note on the computer is ok..

Comment: Wow I did not know any of that. I will check that out if I get a second look at the machine. Yeah, machine is about 5 years old, dirty and been probably in a hot space. I had just never encountered this before. Thanks for the info @barlop !!